# Person I bought laptop from is sharing AVG subscriptions with me without my knowledge

Tags: laptop, vpn, bluetooth, anti-virus, subscription

Should I be creeped out by this? I bought my laptop from this guy in my town about 5 months ago and immediately downloaded AVG as I normally do after purchasing new PC / laptops. After I did my scanning today at the top of the box I noticed there was a box that indicated that I had purchased the VPN and it had the Install button under it. I don't remember buying VPN but I thought maybe I did as I was considering it, and had just forgotten it??  After I installed it I started poking around, which I had never done before cuz I usually just downloaded forget. I don't remember signing up for an AVG account either but again I thought maybe I did so I tried signing in, and of course had to use the forgot my PW option. After getting in succesfully, and went to look to see where to find when I purchaes the VPN. Well this is what I found instead. This is the guy I bought the laptop from. I don't really know him, I just know of him through our community as he works on, and sells laptops. This is the second laptop I had purchased from him. Why would he share his his AVG tools with me? And what does this mean, like does he have access to my personal info or my pics. We never had a conversation about sharing anything. Also I had already had to take my laptop back over to him as I noticed I couldn't get the bluetooth to work and there were multiple Bluetooth devices labeled with his name. I tried removing these devices but couldnt. He removed them for me then gave me a USB Bluetooth device and set up my Bluetooth. So what up with the sharing an how can remove any connnection
to him?

It won't let me post a pic, but the window shows
(persons name)@gmail is sharing this subscription with you.
Its the following subscriptions:
Avg internet security,
Avg TuneUp,
Avg Secure VPN (listed 2x),
Avg AntiTrack

Comment: I would not do it the way you have done. Windows 10 ? Almost for sure. Get all your data off it (backed up). Use the Microsoft Media Creation Link and Keep NOTHING.. Dump it all. Let Windows reinstall, do not use AVG - use Windows Defender (top notch). Update it all and then restore your data and apps.

Comment: Wipe the computer. Start clean. Don’t use AVG. You will never feel comfortable until that is done and whatever headache is involved in doing that is well worth it to just have basic peace of mind.

Comment: If you are concerned just uninstall AVG and/or stop using the paid AVG subscription.  What exactly Is your question?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the built in tools to reset Windows completely. You should have done this when you purchased the computer in the first place.

Second, you should not install AVG. AVG is an OK product, but not superior in any way to the built in Windows Defender. If you are using the free AVG product, don't install it.

These steps will remove any connection the previous owner will have had on the computer and as you won't install AVG again there won't be that connection either.